# Composite C1 - Ultra High Res TIFF file support

Tags: c1-cms

I'm evaluating Composite C1. It will drive two sites. The first is our company homepage with the standard array of product listings, store finder, and contact tools. (We will not sell online). The second is a content portal where our dealers can download assets such as Ultra hires photography for magazine and media advertising.

The key deciding factors in choosing Composite C1 for the company are:

1. Can the Composite C1 drive both sites using one set of images?
2. Can the Composite C1 intelligently handle extremely large TIFF files? (up to 250MB worst case).

Answer (score 0):

There're shouldn't be any problems with downloading huge files, as the default media request handler supports the "accept-ranges" http header. Thumbnail generation may not work though, as it hasn't been tested on files that big, and the built in code may suffer OutOfMemory exception or have some performance issues. Should you need the thumbnail generation, you may have to do some customizations, but my guess is - it may not be supported in the other CMS systems as well.